# php parse errors won't show

Tags: php

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 + nginx + php-fpm 5.4

If I set `display_errors = On` in php.ini all errors are printed. If Instead I set that to off and then use ini_set('display_errors, '1'); directly in the script they will show as well but not the parse errors, just a blank page. I tried to play with error_reporting too and E_STRICT but I couldn't find a way!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you disable `display_errors` in `php.ini`, and later enable it in your PHP script using `ini_set()`, **it will only be enabled after the line containing that `ini_set()` call has been executed**.

Parse errors occur **before the PHP script even starts** -- when the PHP file is parsed *(hence the "parse error" name)*.

Which means they occur before your `ini_set()` has even a chance of being executed -- which means that, in your case, `display_errors` is not enabled when the parse error occurs ; and, as a consequence, you don't get anything displayed.

Comment: so they only solution to show parse errors is to enable it in the ini file?

Comment: it seems pretty logical -- and kind of fits with the second note on http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors *(which says "fatal", but the idea is there)*

Comment: yes, i have added ( un commented )  the following lines, and the parse errors are being displayed now.

 error_reporting
   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
   Development Value: E_ALL
   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Answer (score 10):

here I am **years** after this was answered, but I found a way around this.

For the script I'm writing, I created a second script which includes the ini_set() directives, followed by an include for the script I **really** am working on.

To with, here is test_run.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

include('./my_script.php');

?>
```

Comment: +1 for this; getting this issue with apache+php7, even though I had .htaccess set with php_flag display_errors on, it seems this one kicks in too late and I was not getting the errors reported. Of course I don't want to enable this site-wide, but just to that directory, and this workaround allowed me to "wrap" a debug version of the script that way.

Comment: This is actually super helpful, you deserve a lot more points than you got here!

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: I have no idea how has it come to happen that I never seen this until now. It saves time. I know is not proper debugging, but it saves time.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from turning on `display_errors`, you can also watch error logs. Typically, running Ubuntu + apache, your error log is going to be in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`. To watch in real time what's happening, you run something like `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`.

This can sometimes be more straightforward than fussing with php settings.

Comment: The question asks about nginx, not apache.

Answer (score 0):

**You must enable error displaying in the php.ini file **

I have added ( un-commented ) the following lines, and the parse errors are being displayed now.

```
error_reporting 
Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED 
Development Value: E_ALL
Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Or the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)