# Why does Apache crash while executing following PHP code?

Tags: php, arrays, apache

```
$reset_Array=(); // I forgot to put the keyword "array"
```

Correct way should be

```
$rest_Array= array();
```

Why does `Apache` crash when I try to execute wrong code.

What is happening internally?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using (5.2.x?) and on which platform (Linux? Windows?)?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Apache crashes.  Most likely, PHP aborts execution due to an error.  You should be getting `500 Internal server error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Apache crashes.  What happens is your PHP execution aborts, resulting in you seeing `500 Internal server error`.  This is due to the fact that syntax

```
$reset_Array=();
```

is invalid in PHP.  PHP is trying to parse this line and encounters an error.  It returns this error and the execution aborts.  Try the following: put in a new file `test.php` the following:

```
<?php

$reset_Array=();

?>
```

And execute this with a command-line interpreter with `-l` parameter (*lint* - syntax checking):

```
$ php -l test.php
```

You will get the following error:

```
$ php -l publish/test.php 
PHP Parse error:  parse error in test.php on line 3
Errors parsing test.php
```

Once PHP encounters this error, it cannot continue executing the script, because it cannot parse it.  Hence you receive an error when you try executing it under Apache.

P.S. The above commands are shown from unix/linux shell.  If you are running under windows, then your prompt may be something like `C:\Documents >` instead of `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. On thorough study of the code i found it was something else that was resulting in crash. And yes "error_reporting" helped me in the debugging the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apache isn't crashing. It's just no errors are being displayed.

You could look at the errors in the `error_log` file, which resides in the same directory as your php script.

What you could do is look in your `php.ini` file for the uncommented line `error_reporting = foo`. Change that `foo` to `E_ALL`.

Then it should show the errors, instead of just simply so-called 'crashing'.

Comment: Note that this _doesn't_ display parsing errors - I needs to fully parse the file before beginning to execute the script. Since it's a parse error, it never gets as far as execution. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667432/156755). To enable parsing errors being displayed, you need to do it in your ini file