# Count Total Record in Database for Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanna show 20% users from total users in my database. This is my code in PHP, but I'm using limit 3 for showing users. But how if I wanna show 20% from total users? It means I have to count all rows in my field and multiply it with 0.2. But it doesn't work. So this is my begining code that I don't change it yet.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php

      function getName($id){
        $d=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infouser WHERE ID_User='$id' "));   
        return $d['fullname'];
    } 


    $sqlx= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM correlation WHERE ID_User = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' ORDER BY result DESC limit 3");
    $i=0;
    while(
        $datax=mysql_fetch_array($sqlx))
        {       
        $i++;
    $ID_User=$data['ID_User'];
    $u[$i]=$ID_User;
    ?>


        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i?></td>
          <td><?php echo getName($datax['ID_User_Recommendation'])?></td>
          <td><a href= "test.php?page_owner=<?PHP echo base64_encode(strip_tags($datax['ID_User_Recommendation']));?>" >View Profile</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php    }
    ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've edited my last post, to make it clearly. Because I've trying with the answer but still stuck and doesn't work. So here, I give my code that I don't change. Please help, because it's not simple as I think. Thank you in advance anyway. **Btw, that file I included to another file, which that another file is already included with file for connection to database.**

Comment: You seem quite confused.  You are not even running the first query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ya a lil bit, I've been trying from phpmyadmin with `SELECT *, COUNT(ID_User_Recommend) FROM 'correlation'` and it shows the right answer, it's 6. But, when I tried in my php code and echo the variable, it just showing mysql syntax, not the answer.

Comment: First of all, the page is going to be empty because your syntax is incorrect.
You should change the setting display_errors in your php.ini file (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667432/977026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = new mysqli ('HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASS','DB'); //change to your values
$rec_user =("SELECT ID_User_Recommend  FROM correlation");
if ($result = $sql->query($rec_user)){
    $limiter = $result->num_rows;
    $result->free();
}
$limit = round($limiter * 0.2,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
$iduser = $_SESSION['iduser'];
$sqlx= "SELECT * FROM correlation ORDER BY result DESC limit $limit";

if ($result=$sql->query($sqlx)) {


while($datax=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {       

echo $datax['ID_User'];
}
}
?>
```

This will give you a number from the first query which mysql can handle and will run the query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the page is going to be empty because your syntax is incorrect.
You should change the setting display_errors in your php.ini file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667432/977026) so that the errors are displayed and you can know what to fix.

There are quite a few things wrong:

- Your first query is also not even being executed
- You are multiplying the query text, that doesn't make any sense
- In that query, the * should not be there
- Your while is not being closed, so that's a syntax error
- You should also avoid using mysql extension, and prefer the mysqli extension.
- Try to give logical names to your variables
- Be very strict in using good indentation, that helps a lot on maintaining the code afterwards
- You are not printing anything, so of course the page is going to be empty
- Take care when adding variables to your query, this can be used to hack your site. To make sure the ID is valid, you can cast it to integer. Otherwise, use mysqli_real_escape_string (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_SESSION['iduser'];
$user_query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(ID_User_Recommend) FROM correlation WHERE ID_User = $id");
if ($user_count = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)) {
    $limit = (int)$user_count[0]/5;

    $list_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM correlation WHERE ID_User = $id ORDER BY result DESC limit $limit");
    $users = array();
    while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list_query)) {
        $users[] = $user['ID_User'];
    }
    print_r($users);
    mysqli_free_result($list_query);
}
mysqli_free_result($user_query);
?>
```

Comment: This won't give any results whenever $user_count is not divideable with 5

Comment: It's rounding down, so if there are 4 records, none will be displayed. But if you have 6, one should be displayed. The wished behavior is not described in the question, but you can indeed add a round or ceiling to that line.

Comment: Not sure about that, if there are 6 rows in the table, 6/5 = 1.2 - means you pass "... limit 1.2" to the query, and this will cause an error. Or am I missing something?

Comment: still doesn't show anything. Please see my edited post. I've change it with my pure code. My beginning code that still use limit 3 for showing users. Thankyou in advance for your help :)